# Clustering in Euclidean space

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Let $P_1,\cdots,P_m$ be points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that the distance between any $P_i,P_j$ is less than 1.

Let $p_{i,j}$ be a probability distribution on pairs of these points, that is for $1\leq i,j\leq m$, $p_{i,j}\geq 0$ and $\sum_{i,j} p_{i,j}=1$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ be such that
$$\sum_{d(P_i,P_j)>\epsilon} p_{i,j}<\epsilon.$$

Is there a way to choose $\epsilon'$ and $\delta$ and cluster these points into groups satisfying these three conditions?

1. $\epsilon'$ and $\delta$ only depend on $\epsilon$, not on $n,m$. As $\epsilon$ goes to 0, $\epsilon'$ and $\delta$ go to 0 also.
2. Any two points in the same group have distance less than $\epsilon'$.
3. The total probability of pairs of points from different groups is less than $\delta$.

Comment: What is $p_{i,j}$?

Comment: a probability distribution.

Answer (score 1):

$\let\eps\epsilon$**1.** There is no such way independent of $n$.

Indeed, assume that for some suitable small $\eps$ there exist $\eps'<1/10$ and $\delta<1/2$. For $n=1/\eps^2$ let your set of points be $\{0,\eps\}^n$, and distribute $p_{i,j}$ uniformly over the edges of the cube. We claim that no desired clustering is possible.

Indeed, consider any cluster; wlog, it contains $0$. Now we compare the number of edges inside it with the number of edges from it to the outside; we claim that the ratio of these two numbers is at most, say, $1/10$. Notice that the *weight* (i.e. the number of coordinates equal to $\eps$) of each point in the cluster is at most $n/100$.

Let us reconstruct our cluster starting from $0$ and adding the points one by one in non-decreasing order of weights. Each time we add a point, we remove at most $n/100$ edges going outside (the ones from the new point to the previously added), add at most $n/100$ edges inside (the same ones), and add at least, say, $98n/100$ edges going outside (the ones from the new point to the points with greater weights). Thus at each step the estimate is confirmed.

Therefore, the total number of edges inside the clusters is not greater than $1/5$ times the number of other edges, and we failed to clusterize the points in a required manner.

**2.** On the other hand, if we **fix** the dimension $n$, then the claim holds, even if the diameter 1 condition is omitted. Indeed, one may choose randomly the orthonormal base and dissect the whole space by hyperplanes  into cubes of side $\eps'/\sqrt{n}$ (the offsets are also chosen uniformly random). The clusters will be the sets in one cube.

Indeed, each segment of length $\leq\eps$ will be crossed by a hyperplane of fixed direction with probability of order $\eps/\eps'$ (sorry, I omit the computations right now), so at average the sum of $p_{i,j}$ over the small crossed segments $P_iP_j$ will be small (if we choose an appropriate $\eps'/\eps$).

Comment: @llya One issue about your example, the dimension depends on $\epsilon$. Therefore, such example does not imply our claim is not true.

Comment: Well, you asked $\epsilon'$ and $\delta$ to depend on $\epsilon$ only, not on $n$. Thus, in seekine,a counterexample we may choose a dimension dependent on $\epsilon$. OTOH, if we fix the dimension, then the clustering is possible, as the second part states.

Comment: According to you second statement, in case that $n$ depends on $\epsilon$, $\epsilon'\delta$ can be chosen as function of $n,\epsilon$. Therefore, they can be chosen as function of $\epsilon$ in you example.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. The first part of my answer is an answer to exactly what you have asked. The second part is just a side remark on what would happen if $n$ were fixed. You seem to have some issues with one of these parts --- which one?

Comment: This is what happens in the first part. You need $\eps$ and $\delta$ to depend on $\eps$ only. Moreover, you need them to tend to $0$ s $\eps\to0$. Thus you may choose some very small $\eps$ such that $\eps'$ and $\delta$ are aslo small. Now, the clusterization restricted by these parameters should be possible for _all_ $m$ and _all_ $n$. I show that this is not the case --- so I can, given these values of $\eps$ (and $\eps'$, $\delta$), choose $n$ as I like.

Comment: According to your second point, $\epsilon'$ and $\delta$ are functions of $n$ and $\epsilon$, says $f(n,\epsilon)$ and $g(n,\epsilon)$. OTOH, in your first example, $n$ is already function of $\epsilon$, says, $h(\epsilon)$. Therefore, it is $f(h(\epsilon),\epsilon)$ and $g(h(\epsilon),\epsilon)$, functions of $epsilon$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45484/discussion-between-ilya-bogdanov-and-gondolf).

Comment: one more point, does your example satisfy my condition?

Comment: It seems so;) except for that it's diameter is exactly 1. That doesn't nmatter much.

Comment: the distance between any two points is larger Than eps?

Comment: There are edges of the cube whose lengths are $\eps$. The rest segments are longer, and $p_{i,j}=0$ for them.

Comment: what if i add the constrain that these points are on unit sphere?

Comment: But the vertices of the cube ARE on a sphere, and its radius can easilly be adjusted.

Comment: I don't understand the weight:  how can a number of coordinates be a fraction?  and where is this relevant in the proof?

Comment: @MattF.: It was an obvious typo: $n/100$ instead of $1/100$. This bound yields all the estimates for the numbers of added and removed edges .